# VBA Outlook Mail .display, recording when/if sent manually

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-office, office-2007, outlook-2007

My code displays a message with basic subject, body, attachment.  Next the user manually updates and customizes the message and should send it.  I want to record when (if) the email is sent.  Is this possible or any tips?

My environment is Office 2007 with an excel based macro going to Outlook.

[Excerpt]

```
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With OutMail
    .To = Email                 '.CC = 
    .Subject = Subj
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .Body = Msg                 '.HTMLBody = Msg
    If Not FileAttach = vbNullString Then .Attachments.Add (FileAttach) 
    .Display
End With
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is entirely possible, using the _Send event in the Outlook.MailItem class.

The way I use it, I create a class called EMail Watcher, so when I create the email and do the .Display, I then create a new EMailWatcher object and tell it to watch that email for send, then report back when it happens.

Here's the class as I use it.  Basically, I also optionally can set the BoolRange so that if the user sends the email, that Excel range gets updated with True. I can also have the class update an Excel range with the time the email is sent.

```
Public BoolRange As Range
Public DateRange As Range
Public WithEvents TheMail As Outlook.MailItem


Private Sub TheMail_Send(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not BoolRange Is Nothing Then
        BoolRange.Value = True
    End If
    If Not DateRange Is Nothing Then
        DateRange.Value = Now()
    End If
End Sub
```

And here's how I use it:

```
With oMail
    .To = addr
    .Subject = "CCAT eVSM Utilities License Code"
    .Body = "Message body"
    .Display
End With
Set CurrWatcher = New EmailWatcher
Set CurrWatcher.BoolRange = Range("G12")
Set CurrWatcher.TheMail = oMail
```

Hopefully that helps...

Comment: don't you have to put the Set CurrWatcher before the display ?